# Adding object to vector and then updating it from an iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, variable-assignment

```
class TreeNode {
public:
    Box box;
    vector<int> points;
    vector<TreeNode> children;
};
```

I have this simple node class. I add the node to a vector, and then iterate through that vector like so:

```
TreeNode root;
vector<TreeNode> activeNodeList;
activeNodeList.push_back(root);

vector<TreeNode>::iterator b = activeNodeList.begin();

while (b != activeNodeList.end()) {
    vector<TreeNode> tempNodeList;
    // tempNodeList is populated with multiple TreeNode's
    (*b.base()).children = tempNodeList;
}
```

In the debugger, the children for the node stored in the activeNodeList is set to the tempNodeList, but the children vector for the root is still empty, why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
activeNodeList.push_back(root);
```

will **copy** `root` into `activeNodeList`. All further manipulations with `activeNodeList` will affect this copy, not `root` itself.

You can do this:

```
activeNodeList.push_back(TreeNode{});
TreeNode& root = activeNodeList.back();
```

Now `root` will be a **reference** to the newly added element. But be careful: if `activeNodeList` reallocates, this reference will become a dangling one.